# Vaadin 24.3 throwing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException for Logback LoggerFactory

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vaadin, logback

Upgraded to Vaadin 24.3 from 24.2 and this problem has come back.

Vaadin will not start because it uses Spring and Spring uses Logback, and forces it on you!

The previous fix was the following in gradle:

```
configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
}
```

But now this is no longer working.

Here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from file:/C:/Users/ktaylor/AppData/Local/Eclipse/2023-09/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j2-impl/2.20.0/155c8b9bbdac91d8461d9a403a646e6bd0d365d8/log4j-slf4j2-impl-2.20.0.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.instanceCheckFailed(Assert.java:713)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:632)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLoggerContext(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:381)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:238)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:220)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$starting$0(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
```

Any ideas how to fix this? We are down.

Update: This is the dependency that references logback:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.2.0 -> 3.1.2
```

Update 2: We found a new work-around. Add this to the gradle configuratiosn section mentioned above:

```
        exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
        exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-core'
```

Comment: "Vaadin will not start because it uses Spring" - no, using Spring with Vaadin is an option. So if you think you have to use Spring, because of Vaadin and you don't need it, then opt out.

Comment: Well its not quite that simple. Vaadin's starter app generates projects with Spring already setup, so that suckers you into using it. You do get some good things out of that, and that's the live reload feature and the embedded Tomcat deployment. Ultimately we want to remove Spring but the then have to use an alternative for those features.

Comment: The line from the `gradle dependencies` (?) with `... 3.2.0 -> 3.1.2`
shows, that you are already doing destructing things with your build.
You _downgrade_ the Springboot starter; using a plain project and
excluding like above works just fine (logback not in deps; `bootRun`
shows no logging except some printlns from Vaadin code).  So there are
other things at play and the real source of the problem is not shown.

Comment: The real problem is known. See the solution in Update 2. The downgrade was happening because when using Gradle you have to specify the version of the Spring Boot plugin.  I updated that and it made no difference. The deps are all current now.

Answer (score 1):

Update 2 mentioned above is the solution. Well, its a work-around, not a solution but it works. Spring and/or Vaadin needs to document this because its a real problem that almost everyone is going to encounter.

Comment: Given that the springboot team decided to make logback the default - a base, that is used and trusted for maybe millions of projects, I wonder, why that is a "problem, that almost everyone is going to encounter". Do you want to get rid of logback, for your favourite logger?

Comment: My perception is that logback is less popular than Log4J 2 but I haven't taken a survey. And yes we must use Log4J 2 because we have a framework built around it and we don't want to re-write it for Logback. But the question is, why doesn't Logback or at least Spring not provide for using other loggers?

Comment: There is `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2` - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.2.x/reference/html/features.html#features.logging

Comment: Yeah we tried that a long time ago and it does not work because only our UI is using Spring and the project depends on other projects that do not use Spring but use the SLF4J to Log4J bridge. and that bridge doesn't work with Spring's Log4J support. Spring did not think this matter through.